# unigrams in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, n-gram, cross-join

I have the following table (`tbl`)

```
id | text
1  | example text
2  | this is an example text
3  | text text text
```

and I would like to return this table as output (unigrams)

```
ngram   | counts | n_ids
text    |  5     | 3
example |  2     | 2
this    |  1     | 1
is      |  1     | 1
an      |  1     | 1
```

And I thought of solving this using a cross join (I'm on Presto).

```
WITH 
  ngram_array AS (
  SELECT id, ngrams(split(text, ' ')) ngram_array FROM tbl
 ),
SELECT
  array_join(ngram, ' ') ngram,
  count(*) as counts,
  count(id) as n_ids
FROM ngram_array CROSS JOIN UNNEST (ngram_array) AS t(ngram)
GROUP BY ngram
```

This seems to be giving me ngrams but the columns `counts` and `n_ids` have the same value while I expect a difference because once is the count of the ngram over the entire sample and the second one is the number of documents each ngram is present.

Do you know what I might be doing wrong and is there a fiddle where I can test this online (I know fiddles for Postgres but can't find one for Presto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split text as needed into string array,`unnest` it and use `distinct` option for `count` for ids in `group by`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, text) AS (
    VALUES (1,   'example text'),
        (2,   'this is an example text'),
        (3,   'text text text')
)

--query
SELECT word,
    count(*) counts,
    count(distinct id) n_ids -- count distinct ids
FROM (
        SELECT id,
            word
        FROM dataset
            CROSS JOIN UNNEST (split(text, ' ')) as t(word)
    )
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY counts desc -- order for output
```

Output:

| word | counts | n_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | 5 | 3 |
| example | 2 | 2 |
| this | 1 | 1 |
| is | 1 | 1 |
| an | 1 | 1 |

Comment: thanks so much, this does the trick! But I was wondering if this can also be done using `ngrams` so I can also use it to compute bigrams, trigrams, etc..

Comment: @Brian TBH not sure what ngrams supposed to do with the task, can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Brian also I can't find `ngram` function, only [`ngrams`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=ngram#ngrams) which requires two arguments.

Comment: `ngrams(text, 1)` should be the same as `split(text, ' ')`. So I would to know how to generalise to also computing bigram, i.e. `ngrams(text, 2)`

Comment: sorry, my bad I meant to use the function `ngrams`

Comment: @Brian _"`ngrams(text, 1)` should be the same as `split(text, ' ')`"_ - not completely - first one will return array of arrays. You can use `flatten` or `unnest` on it and then the task is reduced to the one in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean replacing this ` CROSS JOIN UNNEST (split(text, ' ')) as t(word)` with ` CROSS JOIN UNNEST (flatten(ngrams(split(text, ' '), 2))) as t(word)`

Comment: @Brian yes, looks about right.